# C# WPF Caliburn Micro throwsSystem.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException by DisplayRootViewFor

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm using CM first time in a project and it runs good so far. Now I probably made a mistake by trying to assign an event handler within the xaml view.

After that I'm getting a ``System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException for `DisplayRootViewFor<...>` in `Bootstrapper`.

I don't know where the ambiguous to find?

My ViewModel is named `MainViewModel.cs` and the View depends on it called `MainView.xaml`

All runs perfectly before I try to set an event handler in the view, which by the way was for an datagrid if important.

Does anybody has an idea where I have to eliminate this exception?
Found some articles but nothings was the same like my problem I think.

Here is my `Bootstrapper.cs`:

```
public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{

    public Bootstrapper()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRootViewFor<MainViewModel>();
    }

}
```

Exception is thrown by line of `DisplayRootViewFor<MainViewModel>();`

Comment: Do you have multiple classes called `MainViewModel` in different namespaces? Maybe one in the root and another in the `ViewModels` namespace? Other than that, it is difficult to diagnose the problem with such a small amount of code.

Comment: Actually, that's what I was thinking. But I can't find anything like that. But I'll take a closer look at it anyway, thank you.

Comment: I suspect a multiple namespace was responsible. Since I didn't find it, I rebuilt the whole thing and took the content from the broken project. Now everything runs again. Thanks anyway...